# Taurus Transcation controller child in report

Tags: jmeter, taurus

```
Hi I am running running my jmx files using taurus.
execute.sh contains
bzt a.jmx
bzt b.jmx
bzt c.jmx
bzt d.jmx

my Jmx file contain trasnction controller.
eg:
 -TG:
 ---Transaction controller
 ----->HTTP1
 ----->HTTP2

 Scripts are executed sucessfully however the report "kpi.jtl" generated by the taurus does not contain the child sampler.
```

kpi.jtl only shows Transaction controller

I want to view the child samplers of the trasnction controller in the kpi.jtl report .

Comment: Did you get any solution of it? If yes, please share. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Amend your `execute.sh` file to look like:

```
bzt -o force-parent-sample=false a.jmx
bzt -o force-parent-sample=false b.jmx
bzt -o force-parent-sample=false c.jmx
bzt -o force-parent-sample=false d.jmx
```

More information:

- [Taurus: JMeter Global Settings](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Global-Settings)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Comment: not working, it still shows the parent transaction controller.not the child sampler